# multiple instances of httpd24 RHSCL

Tags: redhat, software-collections

I need to create a second apache instance (same version) on Redhat 7.9. The reason for this is that I want to create a second development environment where apache restart will not affect the other apache instance. I am using httpd24-httpd 2.4.34 RHSCL and I am not able to find any related documentation.
Do you know if multiple apache instances is supported for httpd24-httpd RHSCL on RH 7.9 and if there is any documentation I can follow?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a guess tbh, but what about installing the second instance into a container? See [here](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/rhscl/httpd-24-rhel7/57ea8d049c624c035f96f42e) https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/rhscl/httpd-24-rhel7/57ea8d049c624c035f96f42e